# Is there a way to post a message to a Facebook group's feed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm working on a Facebook app that uses Facebook groups, and I'd like to open up a Feed dialog to let the user post a notice to the group's feed. I have a user who is in the group and I've got the relevant permissions as well.

I've tried passing the group's Facebook id in the https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/ feed dialog, but get a Facebook error. There doesn't appear to be a programmatic way to do it either: the group's feed (described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/) isn't documented to accept POSTs either. Is there a way to post a message to the group using the Graph API or one of the other API methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just made a test and it's working as any other wall.

I made a POST to 'GROUP_ID/feed' with a message variable with a value and it worked. I logged into the app as the group owner.

Using [facebook php-sdk](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk):

```
$facebook->api('GROUP_ID/feed', 'POST', array(
        'message' => 'Testing...'
    )));
```

Comment: Ah. So it should work from the API but not from the Feed dialog. Will test it out in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use javascript instead as it wont cause post back of our website.

Check out my application to see if that what you want -> [WooTube](http://wootube.woolei.com)

```
function Promote() {
  var lnk =
    'http://www.wootube.woolei.com?v=<?php echo $_GET["id"] ?>';

  FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      //Post To WooTube Group
      FB.api('/271691796276524/feed', 'post', {
          message: lnk,
          link: lnk,

        },
        function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
            //alert('You have to join the group first!');

          } else {
            //alert("Successfully Posted to WooTube Group!");

          }
        });

      //Post to Wootube Page
      FB.api('/173724382762792/feed', 'post', {
          message: lnk,
          link: lnk

        },
        function(response) {
          if (!response || response.error) {
            //alert('You have to like http://www.facebook.com/WooTubes first!');

          } else {
            //alert("Successfully Posted to WooTube Page!");

          }
        });

    } else {
      alert('Not logged in');
    }
  }, {
    scope: 'publish_stream'
  });

}
```